# Python 3.5: Assigning multiple variables using choices in TKInter dropdown menu

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, dropdown

Thanks to furas I have the following code for ListBox:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_button():
#     for i, var in enumerate(o_vars):
#         print('OptionMenu {}: {}'.format(i, var.get()))
#     print()

    print('ListBox:', l.curselection())
    for i in l.curselection():
        print('option:', OPTIONS[i])
    print()


# --- main ---

OPTIONS = ["Script 1","Script 2","Script 3","Script 4","Script 5"]

root = tk.Tk()

# --- Listbox ---

tk.Label(root, text='Listbox', bg='#aaa').pack(fill='x')

l = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode='multiple')
l.pack()
l.insert('end', *OPTIONS)

# --- others ---

b = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_button)
b.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

When I run it, it gives me the following pop-up (image shown below).  I then make my selections.

[image]

This is where I am stuck... I want to say if user selected Script2 print 'script 2'.  If user selected script 5, print 'script 5'.

Below is the code I tried but it errored out:

```
if l.curselection() == 'Script1':
    print ('test')
if l.curselection() == 'Script2':
    print ('test2')
```

TclError: invalid command name ".92911768"

Also, how do I add a "Quit" button below "OK"?

*Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: when you close dropdown menu then this widget can display only one option - and this is why you can select only one option. Use [Listbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) if you have to select more options at the same time.

Comment: BTW: we use `CamelCase` names for classes - ie. `SimpleFormApp` to make code more readable - [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: NEVER CHANGE TEXT OF QUESTION !!! - add new information below. Now you question is useless fo other users.

Comment: If you have new problem then create new question !!!

Comment: old method for problems - use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. So use `print(l.curselection())` to see what you get.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP change all text in question.

Comment: sorry, new to stack overflow...still figuring out how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OptionMenu` after closing dropdown menu can display only one option - so it can't select more options.

So you can use one of this method:

- many [OptionMenu](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm)
- [Listbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) which can select many elements
- many [Checkbutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

Only with many `OptionMenu` you can select in which order execute scripts.

Example shows all menthods in one window.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def on_button():
    for i, var in enumerate(o_vars):
        print('OptionMenu {}: {}'.format(i, var.get()))
    print()

    print('ListBox:', l.curselection())
    for i in l.curselection():
        print('option:', OPTIONS[i])
    print()

    print('ChecboxBox:')
    for i, var in enumerate(cb_vars):
        if var.get():
            print('option:', OPTIONS[i])

# --- main ---

OPTIONS = ["Script 1","Script 2","Script 3","Script 4","Script 5"]

root = tk.Tk()

# --- OptionMenu ---

tk.Label(root, text='OptionMenus', bg='#aaa').pack(fill='x')

o_vars = []

for i in range(3):
    var = tk.StringVar(value='- select -')
    o_vars.append(var)
    o = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *OPTIONS)
    o.pack()

# --- Listbox ---

tk.Label(root, text='Listbox', bg='#aaa').pack(fill='x')

l = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode='multiple')
l.pack()
l.insert('end', *OPTIONS)

# --- Checkbuttons ---

tk.Label(root, text='Checkbuttons', bg='#aaa').pack(fill='x')

cb_vars = []
for x in OPTIONS:
    var = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
    cb_vars.append(var)
    c = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=x, variable=var)
    c.pack()

# --- others ---

b = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_button)
b.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
OptionMenu 1: Script 1
OptionMenu 2: Script 3
OptionMenu 3: Script 5

ListBox: (0, 2, 4)
option: Script 1
option: Script 3
option: Script 5

ChecboxBox:
option: Script 1
option: Script 3
option: Script 5
```

GitHub: [furas/python-examples/tkinter/checkbutton-listbox-optionmenu](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/checkbutton-listbox-optionmenu)

Comment: thank you!  I'm a little confused on the following step though.  let's say I want to use the Listbox option for drop down menu and I select Script 1 and Script 2....  How do I code up the following: if selected option is Script 1 print "script 1", if selected option is script 2 print "script 2"

Comment: you can use `Listbox` instead of `OptionMenu`. `l.curselection()` gives you numbers of selected rows in listbox and you have to use it to get text from OPTIONS - you can see it in function `on_button()` and in result as `ListBox: (0, 2, 4)`

Comment: I apologize I'm very new to tkinter and classes ... I don't quite understand what you mean above

Comment: use `Listbox` instead of `OptionMenu`. Click elements on this listbox - you can select many elements. Then click button to run function `on_button`. Inside function you can get indexes of selected elements on listbox using  `curselection()` - for selection on image it gives values `(0, 2, 4)`. And then you can use this indexes to get text from list `OPTIONS` - `OPTIONS[0]` gives text `Script 1`, `OPTIONS[2]` gives text `Script 3`, `OPTIONS[4]` gives text `Script 5`.