# Tkinter multiple select from menubar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menubar

I have a problem with making in tkinter a multiple select checkbox of menubar. My code produces a list of choices, but without fields for checking/unchecking them:

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeEyZ.jpg)

I try to achieve similar outlook and functionality to desribed in this post:

[Python 3.5: Assigning multiple variables using choices in TKInter dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626407/python-3-5-assigning-multiple-variables-using-choices-in-tkinter-dropdown-menu)

My point is to create a list of choices from the level of menubar. Here is part of my code:

```
import twitter
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class scanner(Frame):

def __init__(self, root = None):
    Frame.__init__(self,root)
    self.root = root
    self.init_window()

def init_window(self):
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    #text field
    self.entry_1 = tk.Text(root)
    self.entry_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = N+W+E+S)

    menu = Menu(self.root)
    self.root.config(menu = menu)
    time = Menu(menu)
    self.newValue = 30000
    timeToRun = IntVar()
    self.timeToRun = timeToRun
    time.add_radiobutton(label = '1 minute', value = 60000, variable = timeToRun, command = self.setValue)
    time.add_radiobutton(label = '5 minutes', value = 300000, variable = timeToRun, command = self.setValue)
    time.add_radiobutton(label = '15 minutes', value = 900000, variable = timeToRun, command = self.setValue)
    time.add_radiobutton(label = '30 minutes', value = 1800000, variable = timeToRun, command = self.setValue)
    time.add_radiobutton(label = '45 minutes', value = 2700000, variable = timeToRun, command = self.setValue)
    time.add_radiobutton(label = '1 hour', value = 3600000, variable = timeToRun, command = self.setValue)
    time.add_radiobutton(label = '2 hours', value = 7200000, variable = timeToRun, command = self.setValue)
    time.add_radiobutton(label = '5 hours', value = 18000000, variable = timeToRun, command = self.setValue)

    menu.add_cascade(label='Time', menu = time)

    #checkbox
    targets = Menu(menu)
    valueTargets = StringVar()
    self.valueTargets = valueTargets
    menu.add_cascade(label='Targets', menu = targets)

    self.listOfSources = []

    for choice in self.listOfSources:
        targets.add_checkbutton(label = choice, variable = valueTargets, onvalue = choice, offvalue = choice, command = self.modTarget)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. There's unnecessary code in the example, there's missing code in the example, and the indentation is broken.

Comment: The code looks like it's working properly to me. For some OS's you won't see a checkmark unless the item is checked. When I fix all of the obvious problems with your example, it works for me. Your screenshot looks like there is space reserved for the checkmark. Did you try actually choosing one of the items to see what happens?

Comment: From what you have given us I can say your program wont even run as `command = self.setValue` is invalid as there is no method in your class called `setValue`.

Comment: Thank you guys, and sorry for an incomplete code